# SQL comparing two results across rows with similar ID's

Tags: sql

Lets say my table looks something like this

```
id | can_id | last_touch | result
1  | 1001   | 2017-05-01 | good
2  | 1001   | 2017-07-01 | bad
3  | 1002   | 2018-01-01 | good
4  | 1003   | 2019-02-08 | bad
```

I want to create a search that will find rows that will check to see if the the recent `last_touch` date is `good`

How do I do a "loop" through each `cand_id` in the search to find the most recent `last_touch` date and the row's `result` and return if `good`?

Comment: can you tag the dbms being used and show the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want correlated subquery :

```
select t.*, 
       (case when t.result = 'good' then 'yes' else 'no' end) as is_good
from table t
where t.last_touch = (select max(t1.last_touch) from table t1 where t1.can_id = t.can_id);
```

However, same you can also use `row_number()` :

```
select t.*,
       (case when t.result = 'good' then 'yes' else 'no' end) as is_good
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by t.can_id order by t.last_touch desc) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (case when result = 'good' then 1 else 0 end) as is_good
from t
where t.last_touch = (select max(t2.last_touch)
                      from t t2
                      where t2.can_id = t.can_id
                     ) ;
```

Or, if you want only rows where `last_touch` is `'good'`, then add `and`result = 'good'`to the`where` clause.

It is hard to tell from your question if you want a flag or a filter.

Comment: actually ,either one works. Less about the specific answer and more about what I should research :-) This is great. thank you